# pandas DataFrame style lost table border

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I'm following instructions at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html
to set up style for my data frame to become html.

It worked well, except that the table's border of each row/column is lost. It is now a borderless table.

How can I add borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually use the pandas style, so I looked it up. The following code will help you. It's like we have a priority of styles.
The one you set later takes precedence. It seems that you can specify the selector at once, but you need to specify each one.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=["a", "b"], columns=["A", "B"])

style = df.style.set_table_styles(
    [{"selector": "", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey")]},
      {"selector": "tbody td", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey")]},
     {"selector": "th", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey")]}
    ]
)


HTML(style.render())
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## VS Code Specific Answer

In visual studio code notebook editor the accepted answer does not work because the notebook table style has an `!important` in the existing CSS. (Perhaps caused by the dracula theme I am using, or vs code itself?)

To force it to work I had to modify @r-beginners answer as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=["a", "b"], columns=["A", "B"])

df.style.set_table_styles(
    [
      {"selector": "td, th", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey !important")]},
    ]
)
```

[image: screenshot of dataframe output]

**Notes:**

- I added the `!important` marker to the css
- I changed the selector to just `"td, th"` to style both data and header cells with one line.
- I don't explicitly display the result; the dataframe will be rendered because it is the value of the last expression in the cell